# Problema con respuesta de servidor , no cambia el false por true

Tags: javascript, nodejs, post, vue3

Buen día ,tengo un problema y es que por default mi codigo tiene seteada como respuesta
los siguientes valores

```
let response = { status: 0, success: false, headers: {}, json: ()=>null, text: ()=>null };
```

El caso es que lo uso para manejar las solicitudes http , yo envio los datos de mi solicitud a travez de un post a un servidor desde un cliente a travez de un metodo usando vue 3

```
async apuesta() {
  const sessionID = API.config.session.storage.getItem(API.config.session.key); // Obtener el session-id del almacenamiento del cliente

  const apuesta = {
    numerosApostados: this.ticketData.numerosApostados.map(numero => ({
      numero: numero.numero,
      valor: numero.valor,
      sorteoseleccionado: numero.sorteoseleccionado,
      h_sorteoss: this.convertirHoraMilitar(numero.h_sorteoss),
      sumaTotal: this.ticketData.sumaTotal,
      nombreUsuario: this.$store.getters.username,
    })),
  };

  try {
    const response = await API.POST('/apuesta', { body: apuesta, headers: { 'session-id': sessionID } }); // Incluir el session-id en las cabeceras de la solicitud
    console.log(response.data)
    console.log(response)//response code 200 , sucess false
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Ha ocurrido un error:", error);
    throw error;
  }
},
```

a una ruta en mi servidor node js donde tengo la siguiente respuesta:

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "success": false,
    "headers": {
        "access-control-allow-credentials": "true",
        "access-control-allow-headers": "*",
        "access-control-allow-methods": "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS",
        "access-control-allow-origin": "http://192.168.1.100",
        "access-control-expose-headers": "*",
        "connection": "keep-alive",
        "content-length": "193",
        "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "date": "Fri, 12 May 2023 11:14:08 GMT",
        "etag": "W/\"c1-ic+0fMyZpRhNCr9dKk84MTTpVMI\"",
        "server": "nginx",
        "x-powered-by": "Express"
    }
}
```

y en la ruta a que lo mando llega a mostrar en la respuesta el resultado deseado

```
//respuesta server
    res.json({ success: true, message: 'Formulario enviado correctamente', apuestas });
```

respuesta del server en el navegador

```
{"success":true,"message":"Formulario enviado correctamente","apuestas":[{"numero":"00","valor":231,"sorteoseleccionado":"primero","h_sorteoss":"2100","sumaTotal":231,"nombreUsuario":"user"}]}
```

donde si llega el true...

esa respuesta sin embargo no sobre escribe la funcion apuesta

y asi tengo mi metodo en mi componente vue

```
async enviarFormulario() {
    try {
       const numerosApostados = [...this.numerosApostados];
        const apuestaData  = {
        numerosApostados,
        sumaTotal: this.sumaTotal,
      };  
await this.apuesta(apuestaData);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  },
    async enviodeapuesta() {
  try {
    const responseData = await this.$options.mixins[0].methods.apuesta.call(this);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("ha ocurrido un error: ",error);
  }
},
```

Reitero que los datos incluso se guardan en mi base pero no se que se me esta pasando para poder manejar esa respuesta . Agradezco la ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mi problema es que no manejé bien los datos del servidor que me llegaban en formato json
luego de convertir el resultado de la promesa en un json funcionó

```
           const responseData = await response.json();
```